# Does not show values and categories

Tags: javascript, php

This is a proposal calculator, the problem is this.
When you calculate manually, everything works, but when you choose a template, it doesn't work:

1. After selecting the template, it does not show values in input fields picked from product mysql table.
2. Shows only one selected category and not all. (I cannot select other categories).
3. It shows only one selected product not all what in category (I cannot select other products).
   But here it does not work properly only with the selection of templates.
   i think it's just reselecting already selected categories -> products. becouse this.

fetchCategories
fetchProducts
in fetchTemplateData becouse script selecting what inside template, but after fetch to get more categories for manualy reselecting it's broking logic.

[I added photo for visual more explain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5Tjr.jpg)

my logic is not enough to complete this task.

index.php

```
session_start();
include_once 'config/database.php'; 
include 'languages/language.php'; 
include 'assets/session.php'; 



$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


$products = array();


if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $products[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}



$products_json = json_encode($products);



$query = "SELECT DISTINCT template_name FROM proposal_templates";
$templateResult = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$templates = array();
if ($templateResult) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($templateResult)) {
        $templates[] = $row['template_name'];
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>

<?php include 'assets/header.php'; ?>

<body class="bg-gray-100">
    <?php include 'assets/nav.php'; ?>

    <div class="container mx-auto mt-8 pl-2">
        <div class="mb-6">
            <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold mb-3">Proposal calculator</h2>
            <button class="mb-3 bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold rounded add-row-btn py-1 px-3 rounded">Add</button>
            <select name="templates" class="rounded py-1 px-3 border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2" id="template-dropdown">
    <option selected>Select template</option>
    <?php foreach ($templates as $template): ?>
        <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($template) ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($template) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

            <div class="overflow-x-auto">
                <div class="overflow-x-auto">
                    <table class="w-full table-auto" id="proposal-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="bg-gray-200">
                                <th class="w-1/3 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/4 px-4 py-2 text-left border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['category']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/2 sm:w-2/3 lg:w-3/4 px-4 py-2 text-left border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['product']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['quantity']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['unitprice']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['totalprice']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['withtax']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['discount']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['buyprice']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['b2bprice']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['specialprice']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['templates']['power']; ?></th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400"><?php echo $lang['categories']['actions']; ?></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- category selection dropdown -->
                                    <select name="product_category" class="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full">
                                       <option disabled selected><?php echo $lang['products']['category_filter']; ?></option>
                                       <?php
                                        
                                        if (!empty($categories)) {
                                            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                                                echo '<option value="' . $category["name"] . '">' . $category["name"] . '</option>';
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            echo '<option value="">' . $lang['products']['category_filter'] . '</option>';
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- Product selection dropdown -->
                                     <select class="form-select border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full">
                                        
                                        <option disabled selected class="default-option"></option>
                                        <?php
                                        
                                        if (!empty($products)) {
                                            foreach ($products as $product) {
                                                echo '<option value="' . $product["id"] . '" class="product-option" style="display: none;">' . $product["product_name"] . '</option>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="quantity-input rounded w-16 text-center"></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="sell-price-input rounded w-16 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-without-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-with-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="discount-input rounded w-24 text-center"></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="buy-price-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="b2b-price-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="special-price-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="product-power-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                
                                <td class=" px-4 py-2 text-center">
                                    <button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold rounded delete-row-btn py-1 px-3 rounded">-</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            
<div class="mt-8 flex justify-start">
    <div>
        <label class="text-sm">Total Price Without Tax</label>
        <input type="text" class="total-price-without-tax rounded text-sm" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 sm:ml-4">
        <label class="text-sm">Total Tax (21%)</label>
        <input type="text" class="total-tax rounded text-sm" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 sm:ml-4">
        <label class="text-sm">Total Price With Tax</label>
        <input type="text" class="total-price-with-tax rounded text-sm" readonly>
    </div>    
    <div class="ml-2 sm:ml-4">
        <label class="text-sm">Support</label>
        <input type="text" class="support rounded text-sm" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 sm:ml-4">
        <label class="text-sm">Price with support</label>
        <input type="text" class="fullsupport rounded text-sm" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 sm:ml-4">
        <label class="text-sm">Total Discount</label>
        <input type="text" class="total-discount rounded text-sm" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 sm:ml-4">
        <label class="text-sm">Discount Percentage</label>
        <input type="text" class="total-discount-percentage rounded text-sm" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 sm:ml-4">
        <label class="text-sm">Total Power</label>
        <input type="text" class="total-power rounded text-sm" readonly>
    </div>
</div>


        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery v3.5.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */ -->
    <script src="assets/js/flowbite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/session.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function storeOriginalSellPrice(row, originalSellPrice) {
        row.data('original-sell-price', originalSellPrice);
    }

    function fetchCategories(categoryDropdown) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "fetch_categories.php",
            success: function(response) {
                categoryDropdown.html(response);
                fetchProducts(categoryDropdown);
            }
        });
    }

    function fetchProducts(categoryDropdown) {
        var category = categoryDropdown.val();
        var productDropdown = categoryDropdown.closest('tr').find('select.form-select');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fetch_products.php",
            data: { category: category },
            success: function(response) {
                productDropdown.html(response);
                productDropdown.prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    }

    function fetchTemplateData(templateName) {
        $.ajax({
            
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_template_data.php",
            
            data: { template_name: templateName },
            success: function(response) {
                
                console.log(response);              
                var templateData = JSON.parse(response);
                $('#proposal-table tbody').empty();             
                templateData.forEach(function(data) {
                    var newRow = '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<select name="product_category" class="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full">' +
                        '<option value="' + data.product_category + '" selected>' + data.product_category + '</option>' +
                        '</select>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<select class="form-select border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full">' +
                        '<option value="' + data.product_name + '" selected>' + data.product_name + '</option>' +
                        '</select>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="quantity-input rounded w-16 text-center" value="' + data.product_quantity + '"></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-16 text-center sell-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-without-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-with-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="discount-input rounded w-24 text-center" value="' + data.product_discount + '"></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="buy-price-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center b2b-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center special-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center product-power-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
                        '<td class="px-4 py-2 text-center">' +
                        '<button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold rounded delete-row-btn py-1 px-3 rounded">-</button>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                    $('#proposal-table tbody').append(newRow);
                    
                });
                fetchCategories($('select[name="product_category"]'));
                fetchProducts($('select.form-select'));
            }
        });
    }

    function updateProductInfo(selectedOption) {
        var row = selectedOption.closest('tr');
        var sellPrice = parseFloat(selectedOption.data('sell-price'));
        storeOriginalSellPrice(row, sellPrice);
        row.find('.product-power-input').val(selectedOption.data('product-power'));
        row.find('.buy-price-input').val(selectedOption.data('buy-price'));
        row.find('.b2b-price-input').val(selectedOption.data('b2b-price'));
        row.find('.special-price-input').val(selectedOption.data('special-price'));
        row.find('.sell-price-input').val(sellPrice);
        updateTotals(row);
    }

    function updateTotals(row) {
        var quantity = parseInt(row.find('.quantity-input').val()) || 0;
        var sellPrice = parseFloat(row.find('.sell-price-input').val()) || 0;
        var discount = parseFloat(row.find('.discount-input').val()) || 0;
        var originalSellPrice = parseFloat(row.data('original-sell-price'));
        var discountedPrice = originalSellPrice - discount;
        var totalPriceWithoutTax = quantity * discountedPrice;
        var totalPriceWithTax = totalPriceWithoutTax * 1.21;
        row.find('.total-price-without-tax-input').val(totalPriceWithoutTax.toFixed(2));
        row.find('.total-price-with-tax-input').val(totalPriceWithTax.toFixed(2));
        row.find('.sell-price-input').val(discountedPrice.toFixed(2));
        updateTotalCalculations();
    }

    $(document).on('input', '.quantity-input, .discount-input', function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        updateTotals(row);
    });

    $(document).on("change", "select.form-select", function() {
        updateProductInfo($(this).find('option:selected'));
    });

    $(document).on("change", "select[name='product_category']", function() {
        fetchProducts($(this));
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".delete-row-btn", function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        updateTotalCalculations();
    });

    $("select[name='product_category']").each(function() {
        fetchCategories($(this));
    });
    updateTotalCalculations();

    $(".add-row-btn").click(function() {
        var newRow = '<tr>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<select name="product_category" class="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full">' +
            '<option disabled selected><?php echo $lang['products']['category_filter']; ?></option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<select class="form-select border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full" disabled>' +
            '<option disabled selected><?php echo $lang['products']['select_product']; ?></option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="quantity-input rounded w-16 text-center"></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-16 text-center sell-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-without-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-with-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="discount-input rounded w-24 text-center"></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="buy-price-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center b2b-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center special-price-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="rounded w-20 text-center product-power-input bg-gray-200" readonly></td>' +
            '<td class="px-4 py-2 text-center">' +
            '<button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold rounded delete-row-btn py-1 px-3 rounded">-</button>' +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
        var newRowElement = $(newRow);
        $("#proposal-table tbody").append(newRowElement);
        var categoryDropdown = newRowElement.find('select[name="product_category"]');
        fetchCategories(categoryDropdown);
        var selectedTemplate = $("#template-dropdown").val();
        if (selectedTemplate !== '') {
            fetchTemplateData(selectedTemplate);
        }
    });

    $(document).on("change", "#template-dropdown", function() {
        var selectedTemplate = $(this).val();
        if (selectedTemplate !== '') {
            fetchTemplateData(selectedTemplate);
        }
    });

    // Update total calculations function
    function updateTotalCalculations() {
        var totalWithoutTax = 0;
        var totalWithTax = 0;
        var totalTax = 0;
        var totalDiscount = 0;
        var totalPower = 0;
        var support = 0;

        $('#proposal-table tbody tr').each(function() {
            var totalPriceWithoutTax = parseFloat($(this).find('.total-price-without-tax-input').val()) || 0;
            var totalPriceWithTax = parseFloat($(this).find('.total-price-with-tax-input').val()) || 0;
            var discount = parseFloat($(this).find('.discount-input').val()) || 0;
            var power = parseFloat($(this).find('.product-power-input').val()) || 0;
            var quantity = parseFloat($(this).find('.quantity-input').val()) || 0;
            totalWithoutTax += totalPriceWithoutTax;
            totalWithTax += totalPriceWithTax;
            totalTax += totalPriceWithTax - totalPriceWithoutTax;
            totalDiscount += discount * quantity;
            totalPower += power * quantity / 1000;
        });
        support = (totalPower <= 10) ? totalPower * 323 : (10 * 323);
        $('.support').val(support.toFixed(2));
        var priceWithSupport = totalWithTax - support;
        $('.fullsupport').val(priceWithSupport.toFixed(2));
        $('.total-price-without-tax').val(totalWithoutTax.toFixed(2));
        $('.total-price-with-tax').val(totalWithTax.toFixed(2));
        $('.total-tax').val(totalTax.toFixed(2));
        $('.total-discount').val(totalDiscount.toFixed(2));
        $('.total-discount-percentage').val(((totalDiscount / (totalDiscount + totalWithTax)) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
        $('.total-power').val(totalPower.toFixed(2));
    }
});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

mysql:

```
    Table: "proposal_templates"
    All columns:(
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `template_name` 
      `product_category` FOREIGN KEY (category table, name)
      `product_name` FOREIGN KEY (products table, product_name)
      `product_quantity` 
      `product_discount` 
    )

    Table: "products"
All columns: (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    product_code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    product_power VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    product_category VARCHAR(49) NOT NULL,
    product_quantity VARCHAR(49) NOT NULL,
    product_status VARCHAR(49) NOT NULL,
    buy_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    sell_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    b2b_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    special_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    product_description TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_category) REFERENCES categories(name)
)
```

Source code from browser:

```
<table class="w-full table-auto" id="proposal-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="bg-gray-200">
                                <th class="w-1/3 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/4 px-4 py-2 text-left border border-gray-400">Category</th>
                                <th class="w-1/2 sm:w-2/3 lg:w-3/4 px-4 py-2 text-left border border-gray-400">Product</th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400">Quantity</th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400">Unit pcs price</th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400">Sum without TAX</th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400">Sum with TAX</th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400">Discount</th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400">Buy price</th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400">B2B price</th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400">Special price</th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400">Power</th>
                                <th class="w-1/6 sm:w-1/6 lg:w-1/12 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-400">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- category selection dropdown MAYBE HERE PROBLEM?-->
                                    <select name="product_category" class="border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full">
                                       <option disabled selected>Select category</option>
                                       <option value="">Select category</option>                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- Product selection dropdown -->
                                     <select class="form-select border border-gray-400 px-4 py-2 text-left w-full">
                                        
                                        <option disabled selected class="default-option"></option>
                                        <option value="15" class="product-option" style="display: none;">Product 1</option>
                                        <option value="15" class="product-option" style="display: none;">Product 2</option>
                                        <option value="15" class="product-option" style="display: none;">Product 3</option>
                                        <option value="15" class="product-option" style="display: none;">Product 4</option>
                                 </td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="quantity-input rounded w-16 text-center"></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="sell-price-input rounded w-16 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-without-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="total-price-with-tax-input rounded w-24 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="discount-input rounded w-24 text-center"></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="buy-price-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="b2b-price-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="special-price-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                <td class="px-1 py-2 text-center"><input type="text" class="product-power-input rounded w-20 text-center bg-gray-200" readonly></td>
                                
                                <td class=" px-4 py-2 text-center">
                                    <button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold rounded delete-row-btn py-1 px-3 rounded">-</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Does the error occur in the PHP or JS?

Comment: Hello, there is absolutely no error, I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you update your code to show the *rendered* html rather than the php code? What actually gets sent to the browser? What steps have you taken to debug it?

Comment: For debug i use JS concole, and php using E_ALL and display errors 1.
I think problem it's that quantity and discount working good because for them no need fetchs. but for categories, and products needs and template selecting all what need but fetch trigger reselecting. to show all categories from database.